# Doctype issues possibly messing up line-height and line-breaks in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I seem to be having problems with declaring doctypes (possibly) in IE and FireFox.

This is the code that I'm having the issues seen in the screenshots with:

```
<div  id="contact" style="position:absolute; left:81px; top:2440px; width:639px; ">
<span class="contact_header">Getting in touch is easy
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:2500px; width:320px; ">
<br><span class="contact_title">email me:</span></br>
<br><span class="contact_links"><a class="white" href="mailto:hello@superallan.com?subject=Hello superallan!&body= ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hello@superallan.com</a></span></br>
<br><span class="contact_title">tweet me:</span></br>
<br><span class="contact_links"><a class="white" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/#!/superallan">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@superallan</a></span></br>
<br><span class="contact_title">phone me:</span></br>
<br><span class="contact_links">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+44 (0) 7540 308 682</span></br>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:400px; top:2500px; width:320px; ">
<br><span class="contact_title">write to me:</span></br>
<br><span class="contact_address">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;11 abbeyview</span></br>
<br><span class="contact_address">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;crossford</span></br>
<br><span class="contact_address">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;fife</span></br>
<br><span class="contact_address">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;scotland</span></br>
<br><span class="contact_address">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;united kingdom</span></br>
</div>
```

This is my current doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html lang=en-us>
```

This is the CSS for the section:

```
    .contact_title {
 font-family:"FairfieldLTStd55Medium", Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 18pt;
 line-height: 22pt;
 color: #FFF;
}

.contact_links {
 font-family:"FairfieldLTStd56MediumItalic", Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 18pt;
 line-height: 22pt;
 color: #FFF;
}

.contact_address {
 font-family:"FairfieldLTStd56MediumItalic", Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 18pt;
 line-height: 22pt;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

This is how it renders in Firefox and IE.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8h4q.jpg

When I change the doctype to strict it still looks fine in FF but IE makes the line-heights even greater.

Any ideas? Or possibly - how to fix it just for IE as it works fine in eveything else...

Answer (score 0):

I note that you're using `pt` measurements for your `font-size` and `line-height` styles.

Note that `pt` is intended for use with printed pages, and is not rendered accurately on the screen. If you want a pixel-perfect accurate font size on the screen, use `px` instead. (You can also use `em` or `%` for relative measurements, but it looks like you're intending to use a fixed size measurement, so `px` is the one).

For more info, see this page: http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

To quote from the relevant section of the linked page:

> Just like how pixels are dead-accurate on monitors for font-sizing, point sizes are dead-accurate on paper. For the best cross-browser and cross-platform results while printing pages, set up a print stylesheet and size all fonts with point sizes.
>
> For good measure, the reason we don't use point sizes for screen display (other than it being absurd), is that the cross-browser results are drastically different.

...which does sound like exactly the symptoms you're seeing.

Hope that helps.